# read the incoming data from web service

Tags: android, web-services

I have a doubt to be clarified. how can i read the incoming data from web service.

What i want is i get data like this

[ " hi how r u :) " ]. so i need to fetch this message before it is displayed in list view.

sample code:  http://pastebin.com/q3mbuSpU

So I need to replace the corresponding  " :) " with smiley image in local folder before datais displayed in listview from web service. I am working the same topic for more than 1 week. Please guide in in solving this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No this is not JSON service. Its .Net web srevice.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest one idea not sure its working or not.. but you have try...

1) Split your response string when space comes and store in string array.

2) check every character of your string array one by one ... if character ascii value is between a to z and A to Z then its data.. and not then its smiley data.....

Comment: hello sir, I am able to split my web service data and replace it with another string. but i cannot replace the special charcter with image. I get Force close error. how can i replace the specialcharcter(String) with Charsequence image from local folder. please guide me.

Comment: can you tell me what name of image which store in assets or drawable folder... (smiley image name..)

Comment: Name of the image i use is " facea.png " .

Comment: means all time get response string is  :) .. means you have one smiley or different smiley used for all listview data.. how to differentiate image ?

Comment: Letme make it clear. I ve 30 smiley images. In gridview i display all the 30 images. So when i select the image based on the position of the image the corresponding special charcter will be displayed from sqliteDB. Before i send message to service it is like "hi :)". What i need id to replce the ":)" to corresponding smiley image. I am able to fetch the data and replce ":)" with "aaaaa"(example). But when i try to replace the ":)" with CharSequence i get force close error. Hope u have understood my issue. where am i doing wrong

Comment: can u paste some code which you have try... then i will try to solve to your problem...   i think problem is when replace replce ":)" with "aaaaa"... so if i will check code then try to solve....

Comment: try to store in String instead of CharSequence ....CharSequence abc =xpp.getText().replace(":)", New_android_globalActivity.webdata.toString());

Comment: I get the same force close error. Any other options. Is my code for CS is correct. I am doing correctly. Please tell me in this regard.